Curl authentication using json will not work with request headers
I am trying to authenticate through a server using a json request, but in order for the server to not throw a 400 I need to include request headers.
for example
curl -v  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d ‘{“Username”:”foo”,”Pw”:”bar”}’ http://localhost:port/Users/authenticatebyname
will throw a 400 error since it doesn't have all the request headers. Along with an error in terminal with curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URLbut whenever I try to add ANY other headers like this
curl -v —H “Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate” -H “Priority: u=1” -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d ‘{“Username”:”foo”,”Pw”:”bar”}’ http://localhost:port/Users/authenticatebyname 
it will completely ignore the accept-encoding and priority headers and will instead throw back
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: —H
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
* Could not resolve host: deflate”
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: deflate”
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

and THEN throw the 400 error
I am not sure if I have the original request formatted wrong with the content type header, but if I take it out it will throw a 415 since it expect a json request.
I don't know why it's not recognizing the other headers as headers, and throwing that curl error.
edit: I moved the URL in front of -v and that got rid of the first curl error when posting without request headers. With request headers I still get the curl errors, and they don't work as intended.
I also get this error with the 400 {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"errors":{"$":["\u00270xE2\u0027 is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"request":["The request field is required."]}
edit 2: I also tried getting rid of the apostrophes like the 400 error said with “{/“Username/”:/”foo/”,/”Pw/”:/”bar/”}” but this also refused to work, and returned same error

You appear to have the wrong type of quotes in the command -- fancy unicode quotes (‘ and “), rather than plain ascii quotes (' and "). There might be other problems, but this absolutely needs to be fixed. This is probably because you're using an editor that auto-converts them ("smart quotes" or some such); turn that off or use an editor that doesn't mess with things. Also: shellcheck.net is good at spotting problems like this, so I recommend using it to check your code.

@GordonDavisson that seemed to help with the json data, and gets rid of the 400 jargon error code. Now it just returns error processing request, but the headers still won't work.

Clarify the exact curl command you are using. Ensure correct quotes and dashes are used in the command.

The issue was I had the wrong type of quotes in both my header and json request, replacing them with ascii quotes let me use the request headers and json packet.
edit: if you want to send auth commands in curl, inspect element and copy as cURL under the post in networking
